# understanding data as JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a data attribute as a selector for Jquery, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I'm trying:

#### JS

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.upload-data-form", function(e) {
  $("[data-upload-submit]").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

#### HTML

```
<%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", data: "upload-submit" %>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not HTML. Looks like a templating language (erb?)

Comment: Don't know what's that weird HTML syntax, but I understand it correctly the selector should be `$('[data="upload-submit"]').attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: Is `data` attribute expected to set `HTMLElement.dataset`? Can you include rendered HTML at Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", data: "upload-submit" %>
```

what output when it render as html?

assumming it will render as

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data "upload-submit" />
```

try

```
$('input[data="upload-submit"]')
```

or

```
$('[data="upload-submit"]')
```